# Cambiar el valor por anotación en SpringBoot Json

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

estoy usando Springboot , necesito cambiar el valor de una variable cuando se envía por JSON.

El problema es que en la base de datos sólo admite 0 ó 1 y el cliente espera true o false.

SpringBoot->

```
@JsonProperty("required")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.BOOLEAN)
private int typerequired;

public int getTyperequired() {
    return typerequired;
}

public void setTyperequired(int typerequired) {
    this.typerequired = typerequired;
}
```

Angular2->

```
 console.log("LOS DATOS " , data);
 console.log(typeof(data[0].type));
```

Obtengo 1 de tipo Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la solución, para cambiar los valores en Java  y poder enviar un JSON cambiando los valores.

```
@JsonProperty("required")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.BOOLEAN)
private int typerequired;
```

---

```
 @JsonGetter ("required")
 public boolean typeRequired () {

    boolean required = true;

    if(this.typerequired == 0) {
             required = false;
    }

     return required; 
    }
```

Comment: Aparte de que no sigues las convenciones de Java, podrías hacer algo como `return this.typerequired!=0;` para simplificar el método

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedo ver en tu código:

- El atributo en Java se llama `typerequired`.
- Lo has anotado para que en el JSON aparezca como `required`.
- En Javascript lo buscas como `type`.

Por tanto el error debería resolverse al cambiar `data[n].type` por `data[n].required`